# Solution to the ODE $y'(t) =\phi(t) - \alpha(t) y(t)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I encounter the following ODE:
$$ \frac{\partial y(t)}{\partial t} = exp(-\beta t) \alpha - y(t)(\gamma +\exp(-\beta t))$$
with $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $\gamma$ real scalars.
and $y(0)=1.0$

How to solve it in order to get $y(t)$ ?

Comment: Hint: Integrating factor

Comment: What do you mean ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start with, rewrite the equation in standard form, $$y'(t)+[\gamma+\exp(-\beta{t})]y(t)=\alpha\exp(-\beta{t}).$$ Let $c(t)=\gamma+\exp(-\beta{t}),$ so $$y'(t)+c(t)y(t)=\alpha\exp(-\beta{t}),$$ and let $$I(t)=\exp\left(\int_0^tc(t')\,\mathrm{d}t'\right).$$ You can prove that $$I'(t)=c(t)\exp\left(\int_0^tc(t')\,\mathrm{d}t'\right)=c(t)I(t).$$ Therefore, multiplying the differential equation by $I(t)$ results in $$I(t)y'(t)+c(t)I(t)y(t)=I(t)y'(t)+I'(t)y(t)=(I\cdot{y})'(t)=I(t)\alpha\exp(-\beta{t}).$$ Therefore, $$I(t)y(t)-I(0)y(0)=\alpha\int_0^tI(t')\exp(-\beta{t'})\,\mathrm{d}t'.$$ Now $I(0)y(0)=1,$ given the initial conditions. However, to proceed further, we need to find a simpler formula for $I(t).$ notice that $$\int_0^t\gamma+\exp(-\beta{t'})\,\mathrm{d}t'=\begin{cases}\gamma{t}+\frac{1-\exp(-\beta{t})}{\beta}&\beta\neq0\\(\gamma+1)t&\beta=0\end{cases}$$ so $$I(t)=\begin{cases}\exp\left(\frac1{\beta}\right)\exp(\gamma{t})\exp\left(-\frac{\exp(-\beta{t})}{\beta}\right)&\beta\neq0\\\exp((\gamma+1)t)&\beta=0\end{cases}.$$ In the case that $\beta=0,$ this means that $$\alpha\int_0^tI(t')\exp(-\beta{t'})\,\mathrm{d}t'=\begin{cases}\alpha{t}&\gamma=-1\\\alpha\frac{1-\exp((\gamma+1)t)}{\gamma+1}&\gamma\neq-1\end{cases},$$ implying that $$y(t)=\begin{cases}(1+\alpha{t})\exp(-(\gamma+1)t)&\gamma=-1\\\exp(-(\gamma+1)t)+\frac{\alpha}{\gamma+1}\exp(-(\gamma+1)t)-\frac1{\gamma+1}&\gamma\neq-1\end{cases}.$$ Naturally, the case where $\beta\neq0$ is much trickier, as $$\alpha\int_0^tI(t')\exp(-\beta{t'})\,\mathrm{d}t'=\alpha\exp\left(\frac1{\beta}\right)\int_0^t\exp(\gamma{t'})\exp\left(-\frac{\exp(-\beta{t'})}{\beta}\right)\exp(-\beta{t'})\,\mathrm{d}t'.$$ Notice that if we let $s=-\frac{\exp(-\beta{t})}{\beta},$ then $\frac{\mathrm{d}s}{\mathrm{d}t}=\exp(-\beta{t}),$, and $-\beta{s}=\exp(-\beta{t}),$ implying $\ln(-\beta{s})=-\beta{t},$ so $t=-\frac{\ln(-\beta{s})}{\beta},$ and thus, $\exp(\gamma{t})=\exp\left(-\frac{\gamma}{\beta}\ln(-\beta{s})\right).$ To explore further, if $\beta\lt0,$ then $$\exp\left(-\frac{\gamma}{\beta}\ln(-\beta{s})\right)=\exp\left(-\frac{\gamma}{\beta}\ln(-\beta)\right)\exp\left(-\frac{\gamma}{\beta}\ln(s)\right)=(-\beta)^{-\frac{\gamma}{\beta}}s^{-\frac{\gamma}{\beta}},$$ hence $$\alpha\exp\left(\frac1{\beta}\right)\int_0^t\exp(\gamma{t'})\exp\left(-\frac{\exp(-\beta{t'})}{\beta}\right)\exp(-\beta{t'})\,\mathrm{d}t'$$ $$=\alpha(-\beta)^{-\frac{\gamma}{\beta}}\exp\left(\frac1{\beta}\right)\int_{-\frac1{\beta}}^{-\frac{\exp(-\beta{t})}{\beta}}s^{-\frac{\gamma}{\beta}}\exp(s)\,\mathrm{d}s'.$$ The analysis for $\beta\gt0$ proceeds similarly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an Integrating factor which I denote as I(t)
which you multiply in

$Iy'=I\phi(t)- I \alpha(t)y$.
Bring all the y dependent terms to one side
$Iy'+I \alpha(t)y=I\phi(t)$
the left is turned into product rule of differentiation 
so $\frac{d (I y)}{dt}=I\phi(t)$ * *
I is now the following 
$\frac{dI}{dt}=I\alpha(t)$ 
so $I=const*e^{\int \alpha(t) dt}$ which for $\alpha$ scalar is 
$I=ce^{\alpha t}$.

Now put this back into ** and you should be able to come up with a solution :)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).